# how to extract individual pixel(color/rgb) value from one image and transfer to the second image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, rgb, pixel

I'm trying to transfer pixel value from one image and transferring it to other image.
so, basically I have 2 images and my goal is to transfer colors of img1 to 2 according to the regions.

[link to img1 img2 and expected image](https://github.com/hiroto01/images)

here I am aware to extract color channel out of an image , but I am not able to achieve the required result. I'll highly appreciate any help.
my approach:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
os.chdir('/kaggle/input/maskedoutput')
stroke_list = natsorted(os.listdir())

for i,v in enumerate(stroke_list):
    image = cv2.imread(v, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    
    if image.shape[2] == 4:    
          a1 = ~image[:,:,3]  
          image = cv2.add(cv2.merge([a1,a1,a1,a1]), image)   
          image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)
    else:
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)
    plt.imshow((image))
    plt.show()
    copy = image.copy()

    kernel = np.ones((15,15), np.uint8)
    closing = cv2.morphologyEx(copy, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    img_erode = cv2.erode(closing, kernel, iterations=1)# to supress black outline
    height, width, channel = img_erode.shape
    
    for x1 in range(0,width):
        for y1 in range(0,height):
            channels_x1y1 = img_erode[y1,x1]
            
    os.chdir('/kaggle/input/maskstrokes')
    output = natsorted(os.listdir())
    
    for idx,v1 in enumerate(output):
        if(v==v1):
            print(v, v1)
            img_out = cv2.imread(v1, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
            subtracted = cv2.subtract(img_out, img_erode)
        else:
            continue
    
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(subtracted, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.show()
```

here i'm meaning to first erode the original coloured image in order to supress the black outline. Then next extracting color pixels and in the image2 after reading it i'm trying to subtract it with img1 the residual would be the colored outline, but this code is not working gives mte this error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_33/3647166721.py in <module>
     43             print(v, v1)
     44             img_out = cv2.imread(v1, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
---> 45             subtracted = cv2.subtract(img_out, img_erode)
     46 #             if img_out.shape[2] == 4:
     47 #                   a1 = ~img_out[:,:,3]

error: OpenCV(4.5.4) /tmp/pip-req-build-jpmv6t9_/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:647: error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'arithm_op'
```

another approach was to directly pick color pixels from image1 and directly transfer it to second image but as you can see the image has 3 parts with different colors and so its not happening
code:

```
os.chdir('/kaggle/input/maskedoutput')
stroke_list = natsorted(os.listdir())

for i,v in enumerate(stroke_list):
    image = cv2.imread(v, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    
    if image.shape[2] == 4:    
          a1 = ~image[:,:,3]  
          image = cv2.add(cv2.merge([a1,a1,a1,a1]), image)   
          image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)
    else:
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)
    plt.imshow((image))
    plt.show()
    copy = image.copy()

    kernel = np.ones((15,15), np.uint8)
    closing = cv2.morphologyEx(copy, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    img_erode = cv2.erode(closing, kernel, iterations=1)# to supress black outline
    height, width, channel = img_erode.shape
    
    for x1 in range(0,width):
        for y1 in range(0,height):
            channels_x1y1 = img_erode[y1,x1]
            
    os.chdir('/kaggle/input/maskstrokes')
    output = natsorted(os.listdir())
    
    for idx,v1 in enumerate(output):
        if(v==v1):
            print(v, v1)
            img_out = cv2.imread(v1, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
            height2, width2, channel2 = img_out.shape
    
    for x1 in range(0,width2):
        for y1 in range(0,height2):
            channels_x1y1 = img_out[y1,x1]
         
        else:
            continue
    
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img_out, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.show()
```

Blocker image
[image: blocker image]

Comment: Find contours -> find centroid of each contour -> get color at the centroid -> apply that color to the contour

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Do you only want to get the coloured patches in image 1 pasted over image 2 or do you really want to draw coloured lines around the areas as your example output suggests? Please tell exactly what you need!

Comment: @Markus hi!, im explicitly looking for a solution that transfers the color pixels of (img1->img2)corresponding blobs to the other

Comment: @JeruLuke hi! wouldnt finding contours involve us to first convert the image to grayscale?

Comment: @arizona_3 Yes, you will have to binarize the image to obtain contours.

Comment: @JeruLuke definitely!! now onto trying this out on different images with less or more number of colored blobs/elements

Answer (score 2):

I prepared a quick fix solution based on the expected output.

I used the following image as input:

[image]

**Code:**

```
img = cv2.imread('colored_objects.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# binary mask
mask = cv2.threshold(gray,10,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
```

[image]

```
# inverted binary mask
th = cv2.threshold(gray,10,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
```

[image]

```
# finding external contours based on inverted binary mask
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# create copy of original image to draw contours 
img2 = img.copy()
```

In the following, we iterate through each contour.
For each contour:

- get the centroid of the contour (`centroid`)
- get the color at the centroid from original image (`color`)
- draw the contour with that color on the copy of original image (`img2`)

code:

```
for c in contours:
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
    cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
    centroid = (cx, cy)
    color = tuple(img[cy, cx])
    color = ( int (color [ 0 ]), int (color [ 1 ]), int (color [ 2 ])) 
    print(color)
    img2 = cv2.drawContours(img2, [c], 0, tuple(color), -1)
```

Now we subtract the original from the newly drawn image `r`. Based on `mask`, wherever pixels are white we assign white in `r`

```
r = img2 - img
r[mask == 255] = (255, 255, 255)
```

[image]

**Update:**

Expected result for the latest image. The green shade is present on the border as expected. This was obtained using the same code without any changes:

[image]

Comment: thank you! I'm now trying the same on different images with even more no of elements in it.

Comment: @arizona_3 hope it is working fine for the other images

Comment: Hey Jeru Luke! it worked for most of the cases :))), however there was an image i encountered that created a blocker...T_T ive updated the image in the question itself...

Comment: @arizona_3 did you try changing the threshold value in `cv2.threshold`?

Comment: tried these - 50,255; 100, 255; 250,255 etc...that only changed the color from green to others...

Comment: @arizona_3 When I executed the exact same code for the updated image, I got the expected result without any problems. Please see the answer with the updated result.

Comment: strange...i wonder why it didn't worked for me O_o